# How to retrive data for a specefic user from a text file in php

Tags: php, file

I have a text file which stores information like this.

```
user_id cust  rating

1:1,4
2:2,5
1:1,5
1:3,4
1:1,1
1:4,2
3:5,5
2:2,1
```

The first one is the user id who stores information to the file now I want to retrieve the data for that specific user, for example, the user-id one he has a total of five entries how can I retrieve the same please note that I am not using any kind of databases. My PHP code is this anyway.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['user_id'] = '1';
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
$myFile = "data.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
var_dump($lines);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $var = explode(':', $line, 2);
    echo '</br>';
    $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
}

print_r($arr);

 ?>
```

This is giving me output like this

```
Array ( [ ] => [1] => 4,2 [2] => 2,1 [3] => 5,5 )
```

But I want all the output  for the user1

Comment: Why don't you use a database? This is exactly what they are there for. If you don't want to install a full fledged database server you can just use SQLite

Comment: You should be able to read the file as a CSV file - have you tried this yet?

Comment: I dont want to use a database any way what is the advantage csv is going to bring over txt file

Comment: I know i can use a database but my question is specefically regarding the text file

Comment: _“any way what is the advantage csv is going to bring over txt file”_ - the comment said you should try to _read_ this like you would with a CSV file - meaning `fgetcsv` or `str_getcsv`

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here really. Have you tried using functions like e.g. [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and/or [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) ?

Comment: @apokryfos I have edited the code

Answer (score 1):

If you already have this:
`Array ( [1] => Anthony, 2 [2] => Amar, 1 [3] => Ram 5 )`

You could use the following to get the index you want:

```
$users = [
     1 => 'Anthony, 2',
     2 => 'Amar, 1'
];

function getUser($users, $search) {
   foreach($users as $key => $user) {
      $user = explode(',', $user);
      if (intval($search) == intval($user[1]) || strtolower($search) == strtolower($user[0])) {
         return $user;
      }
   }
}

getUser($users, 1);
getUser($users, 'anthony');
```

Comment: How will I get all the entries for user 1 as an array and also i want to do mathematical operations in at that array. for example 1:1,4
1:1,5
1:3,4
1:1,1
1:4,2 For the user 1 thease are the values to be needed in out put

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `foreach` block with next:

```
foreach($lines as $line)
   {
       $var = explode(':', $line, 3);   // third row
       $arr[$var[0]] = empty($arr[$var[0]]) ? '' : $arr[$var[0]]; 
       $arr[$var[0]] .= (string)$var[0].':'.(string)$var[1]).' ';   
   }
```

This will produce for you an output like:

`Array ( [1] => 1:1,4 1:1,5 1:3,4 1:1,1 1:4,2 [2] => 2:2,5 2:2,1 [3] => 3:5,5 )`

where you can use an `index` of the array as `user_id`. I mean:

```
$id = 1; // or 2 or 3; 
echo $arr[$id]; // 1:1,4 1:1,5 1:3,4 1:1,1 1:4,2
```

If you need the only value (without `1:` or `2:` or `3:`) erase `(string)$var[0].':'.` from code.

So, the line
`$arr[$var[0]] .= (string)$var[0].':'.(string)$var[1]).' ';`

would be next:
`$arr[$var[0]] .= (string)$var[1]).' ';`

```
$id = 1; // or 2 or 3; 
echo $arr[$id]; // 1,4 1,5 3,4 1,1 4,2
```